# How do I publish a Widget to the App Store?

Tags: xcode, widget, app-store

I've been publishing apps to the App Store for some time. But today I'm going to publish a widget which is in a different target within the same project.

I tried to submit as usual, but the widget is not visible.
So the question is, how does one publish an app to the App Store with multiple targets? In this case, an app with a widget.